# assigning a variable, but keep getting NULL

Tags: php, oop, session, variables

I'm working on a project, im trying to assign two variables but I keep getting **NULL** when i var_dump() the variables

my code:

User.php

```
<?php

class TheUser
{
    public $isMember = 0;
    public $userID = 0;
    public $info = [];
    public $user_name = 'guest';

   public function __construct()
    {
        global $mysqli,$config;
        if($_SESSION['the_user'] &&mysqli_num_rows($query = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = \''.$_SESSION['the_user'].'\' '))) {
        {
            $this->info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
              $this->user_name = $this->info['username'];
  $this->isMember = 1;
  $this->userID = $this->info['id'];
        }
    }}



    function LoginUser()
    {
        global $mysqli,$config,$_SESSION;

            if($_SESSION['the_user']) {die('go away');}
            if(!$_POST['username']) { die('username already exist'); }
            if(!$_POST['password']) { die('password is required...'); }

if(!mysqli_num_rows($query = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = \''.$_POST['username'].'\''))) { die('0: El usuario ingresado no existe'); }
    $r = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    if($r[3] != $_POST['password']) { die('0: La contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta'); }


        //if($r[3] != $_POST['password']){ die(' incorrect password'); }
        $_SESSION['the_user'] = $r[1];
        $theUser = $_SESSION['the_user'];
        $this->isMember = 1;
        $this->userID = $r[0];
       die('ok');




    }





}
```

then my controller look like:

```
<?php
include __DIR__.'/../../header.php';
$templateToShow = 'login';

$WhatLevel = 0;

$isAjax = empty($_GET['ajax']) ? 0 : 1;

$KeepGoing = true;


$PageTitle = $config['title'];

if($_POST)
{
    $ala = $LU->LoginUser();
}
//session_destroy();
var_dump($_SESSION['the_user']);
var_dump($isMember);
var_dump($userID);


if(empty($isAjax) && !$templateToShow)
{
    echo $twig->render('index.twig.php');
}else{
    echo $twig->render("$templateToShow.twig.php",[

    ]);
}
```

I know there is no security implemented YET... I'm just doing it this way first so I can fix it later.

What I'm trying to do is to

assign $isMember to 1

assign $userID to the user id that i got from the database

I do not know why but I keep getting this :

**string(6) "admin" int(0) int(0)**
I'm sorry if i do not make sense, but it is 3 am and im so frustrated :/

Comment: i dont see `$isMember`  or `$userID` defined

Comment: @Dagon  they are at being define at the beggining of the class:            public $isMember = 0;
            public $userID = 0;

Comment: your variables are out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you used $_SESSION, so you have to add `session_start()` at the begin of each php files. 
And you want to use variable in other class of another file, so you have to include that file and with this code,

```
$user = new TheUser;
$user->$isMember
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot that I had to call it : $user->$isMember I had it like $isMember :/ now i can go to sleep :D